# How to print without skipping a line in Nim

Tags: nim-lang

I would like to print without skipping lines in Nim.

this is my code by far

```py
int i = 1
for i in countup(1, 10):
  echo "number: "
  echo i
```

I would like the output to be:

```
number: (i value)
...
```

instead of:

```
number:
(i value)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert i to a string with the $ operator, then concatenate the strings using the & operator.

```
echo "number: " & $i
```

Comment: You can simply `echo "number: ", i`, without concatenating and forcing conversion. In my opinion, this leads to cleaner code.

Comment: Compared to the other answer, this is the way to go if you just want to output strings.

Answer (score 4):

You can also write to `stdout` directly with

```
stdout.write "number: "
echo i
```

which will print a newline after printing the value of `i`

Comment: Compared to the other answer, this is the way to go if you want a REPL input: `stdout.write "insert something\n> "`